# How do alter a pandas dataframe column with foreach?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to a get a float from the string, then scale it and then replace the old value with the new, however the "sample" variable only seems to be a copy and not a reference to items in the column.

```
for sample in AmpDataFrame['Sample']:
    split_sample = sample.partition(' ')
    try:
        tempsample = float(split_sample[0])
        tempsample *= CurrentShunt_mVtoAmp
        sample = str(tempsample)
    except ValueError:
        print("Not a float")
```

Comment: Can't you just do `AmpDataFrame['Sample'] = (AmpDataFrame['Sample'].str.split(' ').str[0].astype(float) * CurrentShunt_mVtoAmp).astype(str)`

Comment: Yes that works. I didn't know I could do what I presume is a lamda, like that in python. I'm a C# dev mostly.

Comment: Then what would that behavior be called? It's doing some kind of iteration over the entire series.

Comment: Are you referring to my code or your code. My code is assigning directly back to the original column, your method is working on the iterable not what the iterator is pointing to

Comment: Your code. I assuming behind the scenes it's iterating through the series and performing str.split(' ').str[0].astype(float) * CurrentShunt_mVtoAmp).astype(str) on every value in the series. Which in C# you can do with a LINQ/lamda expression.

Comment: It makes vectorised calls that operates on the entire column rather than individual elements at a time, I don't know c# so I can't comment on how this is similar but this a key concept since fortran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to why what you failed, you're iterating over the row values in the `Series` so any mutations operate on a copy not a view. Besides you can achieve what you want by doing the following on the whole df:

```
AmpDataFrame['Sample'] = (AmpDataFrame['Sample'].str.split(' ').str[0].astype(float) * CurrentShunt_mVtoAmp).astype(str)
```

So this calls `str.split` and returns the first split, casts to float and multiplies by your constant value and casts it back to `str`